# Concatenate two lists in turns

Tags: list, prolog

I was trying to create a predicate that concatenates two lists in such a way that

`test([1,2], [3,4], X)` would give `X = [1,3,2,4]`.

My attempt looks like that

```
test([], [], _).
test([X|L1], [Y|L2], L3) :-
append([X, Y], L3, L4),
test(L1, L2, L4).
```

The thing is, it only gives `true.` output, so it seems like my list at the end doesn't get stored under `L3` var? I'm not quiet sure how to go around that, I would appreciate any tips.

Comment: That would be a "zip" or "interleave" operation. You've got the basic idea, but `append/3` is overkill. You can just write `interleave([X|L1], [Y|L2], [X,Y|L3]) :- interleave(L1, L2, L3).` (note that I changed the name to something more meaningful). Your base case `test([], [], _).` says that if you zip/interleave two empty lists then you get anything you want. Does that sound correct? What should yo get if you interleave two empty lists?

Comment: Okay, so base case interleave([], [], []). and probably need to make some base cases for L1 and L2 being different sizes. Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes, you got it. If you want to handle lists of different sizes, then you need clauses for those. It wasn't clear from your question whether those were to succeed or not. If you want different sized lists to just fail, then what you have will satisfy that. If you wan them to succeed, then you just need the extra base cases which are straightforward: `interleave([], L, L).` and `interleave([H|T], [], [H|T]).` - note that using the head/tail notation ensures the list is not empty which avoids the redundant solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is a good start and nearly functional. Here are a few comments.

The name `test` is quite generic and a better name should be used. This is not only a good practice from a readability standpoint, but generic names can often collide with predefined system predicates. In this case, I would choose `interleave` or `zip` which are common names for this relationship between two lists.

Your base case `test([], [], _)` effectively says that the result of operating on two empty lists is any list you want, which clearly isn't logical. It should be `interleave([], [], []).`

The use of `append/3` in `append([X,Y], L3, L4)` is overkill. You can simply write: `L4 = [X,Y|L3]`, or even more compactly:

```
interleave([X|L1], [Y|L2], [X,Y|L3]) :-
    interleave(L1, L2, L3).
```

With that single base case, you limit the successful solutions to only include two lists of the same length. If you wish lists of different length, you'd want some additional logic to accommodate. This can be done with just two base cases. Putting it all together, you'd have:

```
interleave([], L, L).          % interleaving the empty list with any list is the same list
interleave([H|T], [], [H|T]).  % interleaving any non empty list
                               %   with the empty list is the same list
interleave([X|L1], [Y|L2], [X,Y|L3]) :-
    interleave(L1, L2, L3).
```